# Lambda's in VB.net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, lambda

In C# I would simply do this:

```
myIEnumerable.Where(i=>i.ReturnsABool()).any();
```

How would I do that in VB.net?
I'm stuck on how to formulate the lambda..

Comment: I know it's nt the point of the question, but you can simplify this expression with the overload of Any that takes a predicate: myIEnumerable.Any(i => i.ReturnAsBool())

Comment: It was indeed not really the question as I was just looking for a way to express lambdas, but still I didn't realize there was an overload. Thx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
myIEnumerable.Where(Function (i) i.ReturnsABool()).Any()
```

Comment: I see. Quite a bit more verbose. I start to see why the VB code I received isn't very fond of Lambdas :S

Comment: I don't like the VB syntax for lambdas very much either but that shouldn't stop anybody from using them, they are very useful.

Comment: Until recently I thought Lambdas were not supported as many tools said they weren't but was sure they were, only saw the syntax recently on how to use these in VB myself. They are very useful for inline event handling etc.